# Calculating the partial derivatives of the piecewise function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative, piecewise-continuity

Define $ f:R^2→R $ by

$ f(x,y) := \begin{cases}
 \frac{2 x^2 -4 x + 6 y^3 - 13 y^2 + 8 y +1}{x- y}, \quad &\text{if }x\neq y; \\
 0,\quad &\text{if }x=y. 
\end{cases} $

I'm trying to solve for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,1) $ and  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1,1) $.

I've tried to solve it a few times but I'm not quite sure if I'm solving it correctly. I tried a couple different techniques but I'm not quite sure which one applies and if I'm applying them correctly.
I know neither one of them are $0$ but I seem to get that answer quite often for the partial derivative with respect to x.

Technique 1:

$\lim _{x\to 1}\frac{f\left(x,\:1\right)-f\left(1,\:1\right)}{x-1}=\lim \:_{x\to \:1}\:\frac{\left(\frac{2\:x^2\:-4\:x\:+\:2}{x-\:1}\right)}{x-1}= \lim \:_{x\to \:1}\:\frac{\left(\frac{2\:\left(x-1\right)^2}{x-\:1}\right)}{x-1}= \lim \:_{x\to \:1}\:\frac{\left(2\:\left(x-1\right)\right)}{x-1} = 2$

$\lim \:_{y\to \:1}\frac{f\left(1,\:y\right)-f\left(1,\:1\right)}{y-1} = \lim \:\:_{y\to \:\:1}\:\frac{\left(\frac{\:6\:y^3\:-\:13\:y^2\:+\:8\:y\:-1}{1-\:y}\right)}{y-1} = \lim \:\:_{\to \:\:1}\:\frac{\left(\frac{\left(y-1\right)^2\left(6y-1\right)}{1-\:y}\right)}{y-1} 
= 
\lim\:\:\:_{y\to \:\:\:1}\:\left(\frac{\left(y-1\right)^2\left(6y-1\right)}{\left(1-y\right)\left(y-1\right)}\right) = \lim \:\:\:_{y\to \:\:\:1}\:\left(\frac{\left(y-1\right)\left(6y-1\right)}{\left(1-y\right)}\right) = \lim _{y\to 1}-6y+1 = -5$

The other technique is that I first take the partial derivative to x from the function and call it $g(x)$ for clarity. Then I set y=1 in $g(x)$ (the partial derivative). Then I solve the limit of x approaching $1$ for $g(x)$.

I would really appreciate any help on fixing my solution for this. If it's correct, can someone explain why exactly it's correct and how I can check this. Also are both techniques equivalent?

Thanks $:)$

Comment: For surjection: The integers are larger than the naturals, right?  So does the function map _onto_ every integer?

Comment: Your argument for “surjective” does not work. It only shows that the image of an element of the domain is in the codomain (that is, that this function makes sense). To prove surjectivity, you need to check whether every element of the codomain, here $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, can be obtained as the image of an element in the domain.

Comment: So it would not be surjective? Because all $a,b$ that are naturals will not give every point in the integers set. So could I use a counterexample using the fact that $(-1,-1)$ is an element of the integers, but $(-1,1)$ is not an element of the naturals?

Comment: “Codomain”, not “the integers” (the codomain is not “the integers”, its the set of all ordered pairs both of whose entires are integers). (And the domain is not “the natural”, for the same reason). I’d say you are half right: it’s correct that $(-1,-1)$ is not the image of anyone in the domain under this function, but I would say that saying “because it is not the image of *this* element” doesn’t generally work. You need to show that there is no element of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ whose image is $(-1,-1)$, not that the element you happen exhibit is not in there.

Comment: (cont) For example, say you have $f\colon\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$. And you say “Well, $f$ is not surjective, because $4$ is a nonnegative real, but since $(-2)^2=4$ and $-2$ is not a nonnegative real, then we never get $f(x)=4$.” That’s plainly false. But that is essentially how you are arguing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I made some changes, does it work?

Comment: “$(a,b)\geq 1$” does not really make sense; you don’t compare pairs to numbers. But you could say $a,b\geq 1$ (assuming your natural numbers do not include $0$; mine do...) Otherwise, it is essentially correct. Your proof of injectivity also has a couple of minor issues: you should start with pairs $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2$, not $(a_1,b)$ and $(a_2,b)$ (why are you assuming the second coordinate is the same?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to develope a *gut* feeling of what these definitions *mean*.

Surjective or onto means *every* element gets mapped to.

If $(a,b)\in \mathbb N$ then they are both non-negative.  So for $(a,-b)$ then $a$ in non-negative and $-b$ is non-positive.  So no pair $(c,d)\in \mathbb Z$ where $d$ is positive and/or if $c$ is negative will get mapped to.

So not surjective.

Injective means when things are mapped the are mapped *distinctly*.  There are multiple ways to think of that and test that.  It can mean if two things are mapped to the same think then the things being mapped are the same.  It can mean if you map two different things you get different results.  Or, and in the case this is the best approach, it can mean if you have a result, you can always work backward and find a unique input.

So if $f(something) = (c,d)$ and the definition of $f(a,b) = (a,-b)$ then the $c$ can only have come from $c$.  And the $d$ can only have come from $|d|$ (and therefore $d = -|d|$ and is negative.

Anything else wouldn't work.  If $(a,b) \ne (c,|d|)$ then either $a \ne c$ or $b\ne |d|$.  If $a\ne c$ then $(a,-b) \ne (c,d)$.  And if $b\ne |d|$ then $-b \ne -|d| = d$, so $(a,-b) \ne (c,d)$.

Your proofs as you have edited them are fine.  You just have to *believe* them now.